# How to create a sprites then remove a specific sprite in SpriteKit with Swift by touch?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to create a bunch of sprites and remove them one at a time when I touch them. So far what happens is that when I add the code, the last sprite gets removed and not the sprite I touch.

```
var sprite = SKSpriteNode?()
var touchLocation : CGPoint?


for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)                  
        touchLocation = location
        addASprite()        
    }
    removeSprite()

}

func addASprite(){
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

        sprite!.position = touchLocation!
        self.addChild(sprite!)

}

func removeSprite(){


        if ((sprite?.containsPoint(touchLocation!) != nil)){

            sprite?.removeFromParent()

        }

}
```

Comment: I suppose that for loop is defined inside touchesBegan, and that "sprite" variable is defined as a property (its not defined locally inside some method)? If thats the case, what is happening is that you are creating sprites over and over again, but "sprite" variable will end up by holding a reference only to the last node created.

Comment: I had to remove some junk and that did get removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove touched node:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
        touchedNode.removeFromParent()
    }
```